# How to find row number of a particular value with known column number in csv file through python

Tags: python, csv, row

I am working on a problem to create a function **find_row** with three input parameters - file name, col_number and value. I want output like in given example:

For example, if we have a file a.csv:

```
 1, 1.1, 1.2
 2, 2.1, 2.2
 3
 4, 4.1, 4.2
```

then

print(find_row('a.csv', 0, 4)) would print 3,

print(find_row('a.csv', 2, 2.2)) would print 1, and

print(find_row('a.csv', 0, 100)) would print None.

The code I tried is :

```
 import csv

 def find_row(filename,col_number,value):
     var = str(value)
     coln = str(col_number)
     o = open(filename, 'r') 
     myData = csv.reader(o) 
     index = 0 
     for row in myData:
        if row[col_number] == var:
            return index 
        else : 
            index+=1

 print find_row('a.csv',2,2.2)
```

It is throwing error :

```
   File "C:/Users/ROHIT SHARMA/Desktop/1.py", line 17, in find_row
     if row[col_number] == var:

   IndexError: list index out of range
```

I understand the error now, but not able to improve the code. Any help here guys??!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSV file, the 3rd row has only one column, so 2 is not a valid index.

As an aside, it's cleaner to do

```
 for index, row in enumerate(myData):
    if row[col_number] == var:
        return index
```

Edit: Also, that CSV is going to give you problems. It can't find '2.2' because it actually returns ' 2.2'. Strip the spaces when you read or make sure the CSV is saved the "correct" way (no spaces between comma and content).

Edit2: If you MUST have a CSV with unequal rows, this will do the trick:

```
for index, row in enumerate(myData):
    try:
        if row[col_number] == var:
            return index
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Comment: still throwing same error. And the csv file has no spaces. while pasting over here, it got spaces in the example.

Comment: I tested on my end in both 2.7 and 3.5 and it works fine for me. Can you put your current code in a pastebin and I'll take a look?